# Web application created in STS with glassfish not deploying

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, glassfish

So i have been trying to make this project work for like 4 hours. So help me with this : 
 I have a project which is a web application that uses as database some xmls ( hence jabx). Now i made it in spring tools suite and everything is up to date ( jdk 1.8 etc.). I use as server glassfish 4.1 and i get this errors when it is trying to run it ( of course there are like 1000 lines of errors but it begins here ) :

```
    Severe: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
2016-05-18T01:58:19.498+0300|Severe: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
2016-05-18T01:58:19.498+0300|Severe: log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2016-05-18T01:58:21.169+0300|Info: null
2016-05-18T01:58:21.211+0300|Severe: Startup of context /Assignement2 failed due to previous errors
2016-05-18T01:58:21.211+0300|Severe: Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Manager has not yet been started
```

and it continues for ever. I will make it shorter saying that they refer to

- "Error creating bean with name "
- Severe: Exception during lifecycle processing
- "Severe: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method.."

Also warnings like : "Warning: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina...."

Now i guess this happens because of some dependencies or maven or something, because i work on windows , i know that on mac it would be easier, but at the moment i do not have one .

I will show you the pom, security, web and everything i use to set up my project. What i suspected first was the fact that when i used in the security folder the link for spring security without -4.0, it gave me errors. After i put -4.0 it worked. I know it comes from dependencies, but i just wanted to put it out there.

I can not help with the full log of errors because is very long and is in majority about beans. If you need more info, like the structure or something else just tell me because i really need this project to work ! Thanks.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>cz.jiripinkas.jba</groupId>
  <artifactId>Assignement2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>


    <name>SpringSecurityCusotmLoginFormAnnotationExample</name>

  <!-- Shared version number properties -->
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

</properties>

 <dependencies>
        <!-- pdf -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
      </dependency>



      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
      </dependency>


      <!--
        Core utilities used by other modules.
        Define this if you use Spring Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Expression Language (depends on spring-core)
        Define this if you use Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- 
        Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core)
        Define this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) 
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, spring-beans)
        Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, spring-beans) 
        This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection Container and is generally always defined
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, Quartz, and Freemarker integration
        Define this if you need any of these integrations
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-aop, spring-context)
        Define this if you use Spring Transactions or DAO Exception Hierarchy
        (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
        Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, and iBatis.
        (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
        Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans.
        (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
        Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and Portlet Environments
        (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
        Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
        Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
        Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and TestNG
        This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-version-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Assignement2</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.htl</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
         <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">



<!-- http use-expressions="true" -->
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/library" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <!--here are the pages for admin -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/addBook**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/editBook**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/users**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/addUser**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/editUser**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.html" username-parameter="ssoId" password-parameter="password" authentication-failure-url="/index.html"/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout"/>
    <csrf/>
</http>


<!--authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager-->
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="scan.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. Because i use jabx to read from xml files i did not put the correct path for the xmls. So if you encounter this problem look first for all data to be correct and then for other incompatibilities. I learnt it the hard way ( 4 hours of search )